# Django admin- constrain visibility of models and model instances based on who logged in

Tags: django, django-admin

Using the django admin, I would like to be able to specify which models a user sees when he logs in. For a stretch goal, for each model types a user can see, I would like to specify a filter to limit which instances of the model the user can see.

Could someone please provide a pointer for how to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which models the user can see and manipulate using the admin itself. You can do this when you're logged in as a superuser.

Regarding your stretch goal, a simple answer is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952626/user-based-model-instances-filtering-in-django-admin).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [group](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#groups)-level [permissions in the Admin](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/) (scroll down). Django 1.2 has introduced [hooks for object-level permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#object-level-permissions) too

Comment: Does Django admin provide a hook into which instances are displayed for a given model? If that's available, I can maybe use the Auth framework to determine current user identity and what to display