# User-based model instances filtering in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, changelist

I'm using django's admin to let users manage model instances of a specific model.
Each user should be able to manage only his model instances. (except for administrators which should manage all).

How do I filter the objects in the admin's changelist view?

Thoughts:

- I guess the most elegant approach would be to use [Object-level permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#object-level-permissions). Anyone aware of an implementation of this?
- Is it possible to do by overriding the admin's view using ModelAdmin.changelist_view?
- Does list_select_related have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the admin's `queryset`-method to just display an user's items:

```
    def queryset(self, request):
        user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=user)
```

Besides that you should also take care about the `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission`-methods, eg like:

```
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):   
        if not request.user == obj.user and not request.user.is_superuser:
            return False
        return super(MyAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

Same for `has_change_permission`!
`list_select_related` is only used when getting the admin's queryset to get also related data out of relations immediately, not when it is need!

If your main goal is only to restrict a user to be not able to work with other's objects the above approch will work, if it's getting more complicated and you can't tell a permissions simply from ONE attribute, like user, have a look into django's proposal's for row level permissions!

Comment: Your first peace of code worked great. I also found it here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django-admin/index.html