# filter admin show in django by users

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I add one ManyToManyField to my Users profile:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    news_letters = models.ManyToManyField(news_letter)
```

and replace it with my user admin:

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyUser
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'MyUser'


# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInline, )


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I have news_letter model in my django admin, every user can see all news_letter records in django admin, I want to show just such records that in MyUser.news_letters for specific user.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would not recommend giving your users access to the Django admin. With a bit more code, you can create a couple of views to allow users to subscribe/unsubscribe etc. Still if you need it, here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952626/user-based-model-instances-filtering-in-django-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use authentication in Django. Here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/).

First, you have to create a group with access to 'news_letter'. Second, add specific user into this group. Last but not least, you may have to make different views for different users. Hope this helps.